# How to specify user owning volume created via docker-compose configuration?

Tags: docker, permissions, docker-compose, volume, docker-volume

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  xxx:
    container_name: xxx
    image: xxx
    volumes:
      - config:/some_mountpoint
    user: 1000:1000

volumes:
  config: # <- this volume
```

How can I specify for which user the `config` volume will be created i.e. the mountpoint permissions?

Without specifying those permission `/some_mountpoint` is owned by `root:root` inside the container.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know - you can't. I guess you have to create a custom entrypoint where you can set permissions you need.

Something like that (this is *docker-entrypoint.sh*):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                      

set -e                                                                                                                                                                                                           

user=dev                                                                                                                                                                                                       
user_id=${USER_ID:-1000}                                                                                                                                                                                         

if ! id "${user}" > /dev/null 2>&1; then                                                                                                                                                                         
  useradd -u ${user_id} -m -s /bin/bash ${user} > /dev/null 2>&1                                                                                                                                                 
fi                                                                                                                                                                                                               

mount_path=/some_mountpoint                                                                                                                                                                                 
mount_path_owner=$(ls -ld ${mount_path} | awk '{print $3}')                                                                                                                                                    
if [ "${user}" != "${mount_path_owner}" ]; then                                                                                                                                                                 
  chown -R ${user}:${user} ${mount_path}                                                                                                                                                                        
fi                                                                                                                                                                                                               

exec gosu ${user} "${@}"
```

It also needs [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) in your container.

So your *docker-compose.yml* may looks like that:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  xxx:
    entrypoint: ./docker-entrypoint.sh # <- use the custom entrypoint
    container_name: xxx
    image: xxx
    volumes:
      - config:/some_mountpoint

volumes:
  config: # <- this volume
```

Comment: This is a discussion in Docker world since always, I'm just going to leave some reference links here:

- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2259
- https://github.com/douglasmiranda/lab/tree/master/docker-volume-share-user-host-container